# Reusing index in constraints

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to understand how Oracle determine if the index can be used for constraint. 
For example, the following works :

```
create table temp11
(id int not null,
val varchar2(10),
CONSTRAINT PK_temp11 primary key (id) using index 
(create index IDX_temp11 ON temp11(id,val))
);
--Also, I can re-use the same index for another unique constraint :
ALTER TABLE temp11 ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_temp11 UNIQUE(id,val) using index IDX_temp11;
```

But if I change index definition and make it unique, I get error

> ORA-14196: Specified index cannot be used to enforce the constraint.

```
create table temp11
(id int not null,
val varchar2(10),
CONSTRAINT PK_temp11 primary key (id) using index 
(create UNIQUE index IDXU_temp11 ON temp11(id,val))
); -- ORA-14196
```

** Making val `not null` doesn't make a difference.
Could anyone explain this behaviour?
I don't see why such an unique index cannot used for enforcing constraint whereas non-unique is accepted.
I use Oracle 10 if it matters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I understand your frustration with this behavior.  There seem to be internal obstacles to implementing this and could lead to larger indexes than are necessary.

- With a **unique** index supporting a primary key, constraint validation is done **before** the unique index is modified and **one** look-up can verify whether the entry can be inserted or not.<sup>[1](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2007/12/18/differences-between-unique-and-non-unique-indexes-part-i/)</sup>
- With a **non-unique** index supporting a primary key, constraint validation is done **after** changes are made to the non-unique index and **multiple** look-ups are required to verify whether the entry can be inserted or not.<sup>[1](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2007/12/18/differences-between-unique-and-non-unique-indexes-part-i/)</sup>

A primary key using the leading column of a unique index would require non-unique index constraint logic on a unique index.  This would require changes and/or additions to the logic.

If id is unique/primary then (id,val) is inherently unique, and normally you would not need/want a unique constraint/index on (id,val).

You might want a unique index on (id,val) if there were a query referencing (id,val) and you wanted to prevent a table look-up.  If this is your situation, you may have to decided which is the lesser tradeoff between allowing the table look-up, increasing the primary key to (id,val) or having two unique indexes.  For most situations I suspect the table look-up would be preferable.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thank you, @Leigh

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this helps you, But I tried with Different things.. and this works.

```
create table temp11
(id int not null,
val varchar2(10) not null,
CONSTRAINT PK_temp11 primary key (id,val) using index 
(create unique index IDXU_temp11 ON temp11(id,val))
);
```

What I derive from here is your Primary Key index was with (id) i.e 1 col, whereas ure are using the same for **id,val** 2 cols, Again This is just a wild guess.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but it doesn't really help. No doubt it works if all pk columns are listed in unique index, but I try to reuse index in more than 1 constraints. Somehow it works with non-unique index(1st example), but not with unique...